# windows 10 connection issues

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

I'm facing some frustrating connection issues on windows 10 in the last few weeks.
While my browser work just fine, all native things on win 10 like the app store, cortana or the updater do not seem to have a connection to the internet.

I tried to trigger manually wifi on/off, deactivate/activate wifi devices and so on.

Any tipps of how to get rid of this issue?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Could be DHCP services
Type services in search/cortona; open it, find the service named "DHCP Client". If it is already on Automatic for startup, ensure that it is started. If it is not on Auto, make it auto.

Comment: this service is already running but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft:

Method 1:
You may try running the Windows UI app troubleshooter and check for the issue.
You may try to run the apps troubleshooter and check if it helps.
You may use the Windows UI app troubleshooter to address a number of known issues that can prevent apps from running.

Method 2:
You may refer the article and try the steps provided and check if it helps.
What to do if you have problems with an app

Method 3:
You may try to clear the cache for the Store and check if it helps:
a. Press the Windows key + R.
b. Type WSReset.exe and hit enter.

Method 4:
You may also try to temporarily disable the third party Security Software and firewalls and check what happens. If this resolves the issue, you may try check with the manufacturer of the Security Software for an update for the software.
Note: Enable the security software back after resolving the issue.

Comment: too long to put in the comments

Comment: If you are going to quote from somewhere else you should properly attribute it with a link to the source and quote the text properly. Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing)